# using :nth-child to select lines and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, css-selectors

I am doing a university project at the minute where I feed information in from a set xml file and then place it into a set div using jQuery as individual paragraphs.

At the moment, what is being fed in is something like this:

```
<p class="speech">Blah</p>
<p class="line">Blah</p>
<p class="line">Blah</p>
<p class="line">Blah</p>
<p class="line">Blah</p>
<p class="speech">Blah</p>
<p class="line">Blah</p>
```

Etc.

One of the requirements of the module is to number every 5th line, which I thought would be easiest done by using something like:

```
$("#contents_txt p:nth-child(5n)").append("<span> - 5th</span>");
```

However instead of adding "5th" to the end of each 5th line it is adding it multiple times:

> COUNTESS
>
> In delivering my son from me, I bury a second husband.
>
> BERTRAM
>
> And I in going, madam, weep o'er my father's death
>
> anew: but I must attend his majesty's command, to - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th -     5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th - 5th

I can't figure out why this is happening, because if I change to something like the `.css` selector, I can apply style to every 5th line fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I have made a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/LfpMm/ however it seems to be working in a barebones environment.

A working example on my end is available: http://immbudden.com/siab/siab.html

In order to see what I mean: click on a play, click on the contents nav, click on a scene and you'll see whats happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please make a working example, using something like  http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Barebones example, works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/bRDd5/2/

Comment: i'm not seeing this behavior... http://jsfiddle.net/HCxQ9/

Comment: just edited the question with my jsfiddle too (see edit), something else must be causing it, I have my built version in the edit!

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-extra-selectors.js:4`[1](http://immbudden.com/siab/siab.html)

Comment: just took that out there now, however it doesn't make any difference :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your localscripts.js file. On this line

```
$(this).find("LINE").each(function(){
    $("#contents_txt").append("<p class='line'>"  + $(this).text() + "</p>");
    $("#contents_txt p:nth-child(5n)").append("<span> - 5th</span>");
});
```

Maybe move that second append out of the .each function so

```
$(this).find("LINE").each(function(){
    $("#contents_txt").append("<p class='line'>"  + $(this).text() + "</p>");
});

    $("#contents_txt p:nth-child(5n)").append("<span> - 5th</span>");
```

Comment: Aha! Although placing it just outside this function doesn't work, however if I place it into the click function: 

`$("#contents_1").on("click","p.sceneTitle",function(){
   var act_scene_ref = ($(this).attr("id")).split("_");
   actNo = act_scene_ref[0];
   sceneNo = act_scene_ref[1];
   displayScene(actNo,sceneNo); 
  $("#contents_txt p:nth-child(5n)").append("<span> - 5th</span>");` it works! Thanks dude, was scratching my head for a while there!